# Calculating the limit of a complex number $\lim_{z \to 0}$ $\frac {\lvert z \lvert ^2}{z}$

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, limits

Should I consider $\lvert z \lvert ^2$ = $ z \bar{z} = x^2 + y^2$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe that $|z|^2/z=\overline{z}$. Since the function $z\mapsto\overline{z}$ is continuous, the limit exists and equals $0$.

Comment: You're right, I missed that.

So then we have $\lim_{z \to 0} $  $\frac {\lvert z \lvert ^2}{z} = \lim_{z \to 0}  \overline{z} = 0$ ?

Comment: @carlos1251 yes

Answer (score 0):

Or use that $||z|^{2}/z|=|z|^{2}/|z|=|z|\rightarrow 0$ as $z\rightarrow 0$. Now that $\lim_{z\rightarrow 0}f(z)=0$ if and only if $\lim_{z\rightarrow 0}|f(z)|=0$.